# Do we want to use `this formatting` for reproducing chess moves?

Tags: discussion, formatting

Do we want to universally use (and encourage the use of) `this formatting` for reproducing chess moves?

I use this formatting in my posts, because I think it's clearer, and quickly draws the eye to the moves under discussion, but I'd like to know whether I should edit 1... d5 to `1... d5` where I see it, for example.  I did it [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/772/86), when the original post looked like this:

> I'd concentrate on chasing Black's queen. Nc3 is a normal developing move, and threatens Nd5.
>
> Another move is Pd3, which threatens Bg5. Black's most threatening countermove is 3.... Bc5, which can be met by 4. Be3. If Black exchanges bishops, it opens the f file of the (castled) rook to chase the queen.
>
> No need to sweat this one because Greco is an inferior opening. Just make good developing moves and Black will fall behind in development.

Is this a good idea, or should I not worry about reformatting chess moves?  The work load involved is not an issue for me - it's the community's opinion I want to know.

Comment: Related: [Is it necessary to put backticks for moves?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/26335)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your edit for the notation style Daniel. The regular font for the site is great for words where the characters should nicely flow together. Chess notations however I think benefit from the font you used where each character has the same amount of spacing.

So I think it's a good rule of thumb, although it will mean plenty of updating for questions put forth by new members.

Comment: Thanks for the input; I think I'll start editing a little.  In this stage of the site, it's not too gargantuan a task, spread out over several days.

Comment: I agree, good summary - after seeing a bunch of the edits by Daniel (good thing you have 1000 rep, BTW...) I do like the way that the moves are set off now.  The only exception I can think of would be cases where main lines as well as variations are given, it might be nice to separate the two, but in this case the variations can probably be italicized.